# Extending a class with many implementation that each have main methods in Scala

Tags: scala

imagine that I have a Tokenizer class with a single abstract method.

```
trait Tokenizer {
    def tokenize(sentence: String): List[String]
}
```

I will implement a number of tokenizers that provide an implementation.  I would like for each of these Tokenizer to have a main method.  My first thought was to write code like this:

```
abstract class TokenizerMain(tokenizer: Tokenizer) {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = println(tokenizer.tokenize(args(0)).mkString(" "))
}

class TokenizerOne(val model: String = "foo") extends Tokenizer {
    def tokenize(sentence: String) = List("asdf")
}

object TokenizerOne extends TokenizerMain(new TokenizerOne) {
}
```

However, I get the error "super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name".  I can rename `object TokenizerOne` to `object TokenizerOneMain` but I would like to keep it the same as the `class`.  Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE: this problem seems to be caused by the implicit constructor parameter `model` of TokenizerOne.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a reduced code sample that gives the same error,

```
class Foo(t: Any)
class Bar(x: String = "bar")
object Bar extends Foo(new Bar())
  //                   ^
  // Error, super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless
  // parameter is declared by-name
```

The bytecode helps explain what's going on. From the REPL,

```
scala> class Foo(t: Any)

scala> class Bar(x: String = "bar")

scala> :javap -v Bar

Compiled from "<console>"
public class Bar extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject
...
{
public Bar(java.lang.String);
...
```

We see that the class `Bar` has only a single constructor, which takes a `String` parameter. But we know that `Bar` also has a constructor that uses the default value `x = "bar"`, where does that come from?

```
scala> :javap -v Bar$
...
public java.lang.String init$default$1();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   ldc #16; //String bar
   2:   areturn
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 7: 0
```

Ahh, that's defined in the companion object, which belongs to class `Bar$` (only the Scala compiler is supposed to know about that).

So what seems to be happening is that in `extends Foo(new Bar())` you're trying to access a method in object `Bar` during the initialization of `Bar`'s super-class (which is before the object `Bar` is actually constructed).

If this is not a bug in the Scala compiler, then it's a confusing error message! I can't say which. I filed issue [SI-5000](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5000) in the bug tracker.

As a workaround, you can avoid the default value: `object Bar extends Foo(new Bar("bar"))`.

Comment: I am using 2.9.1.  I forgot an implicit constructor argument on the class TokenizerOne--my apologies.  With the addition of this constructor argument, the problem happens.